# What are good ways to cite personal skill courses on a resumé

Tags: resume, skills

What are good ways to cite self-directed personal skill courses, such as improving memory, time-management, grammar improvement and sales courses on a resumé.

===ADDITIONAL INFO===

What category should these be listed under?

Comment: What kind of jobs are you applying to?

Comment: When you say "self-directed", is this similar to a self-help book? So there is no certification or outside party who would oversee your progress?

Comment: first: have you provided/designed/taught these courses or you have been a recipient? and second: what do you want to do in life?

Comment: Would the job you want involve any sales? If yes, you probably shouldn't think of that as the same as the other courses (it's generally assumed most people are good enough at those things to excel at most jobs without needing a course). Terrible grammar tends to be pretty easy to spot, although a grammar course might  be noteworthy if you'll be doing copywriting or other professional writing. Also, are these certified or graded courses?

Comment: If you took some online course, why not just list that? Ex: `Lynda.com course: C Essential Training`

Comment: Putting them on your resume will tell the recipients a lot about you. Whether it tells them things that you *want* to tell them is different matter.

Comment: @DavidK Correct. But a book isn't a course. One could show the course one took ... a memory improvement course for example. The point the question is promoting is that an employer is going to well favor a person who has the presence of mind to pursue self-improvement.

Answer (score 4):

If these courses are generic, and the learnings from them are the general expectation for your role you are applying for, I would advice not listing them directly as it creates fluff in the resume and the hiring manager may end up missing other important details.

Instead, you can use keywords from the courses in your objective statement, and at other places within the details of the work experience you have for various jobs.

However if the courses are specialized, and is something that is either a pre-requisite or is above the general expectation of the role, then it would make sense to include them in your educational qualifications section, and optionally in the objective statement as well.

This could be the case for industry certifications (PSM, PMP, CISO, ITIL, etc), MOOC courses that you have done online (and have certificates for), executive education courses done at universities / b-schools.